# Orange Dot for Sublimetext3 dirty files

Tags: sublimetext3

Modifying `Preferences/Settings - User` and adding: `"highlight_modified_tabs":true,` gets me highlighted TEXT in the tab for dirty files, but I cannot get the greyed out dot on the tab to change colors as well.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the dirty file dot change to orange like the text on the tab does by modifying the above settings, except I want only the dot to change color and not the text on the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for those who may run into this issue.

After a lot of fiddling around, I figured out that within the `Default.sublime-theme` file on the lines describing the close file button which start at line 729 (for me at least) you will see a bunch of different code blocks that look like this:

```
  {
        "class": "tab_close_button",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["dirty", "file_medium_dark"]}],
        "layer0.opacity": 0.0,
        "layer1.opacity": 0.0,
        "layer2.opacity": 0.0,
        "layer3.texture": "Theme - Default/dirty_circle_light.png", 
        "layer3.opacity": 0.5
    },
```

There are several different blocks like the above that correspond to the `tab_close_button` class for the dirty attribute, presumably related to the background color of your theme.  For me, running Tomorrow Night Eighties - I had to modify the above block which contained the reference code for whatever "file_medium_dark" may be (I just assumed medium_dark would catch my theme since it's, well ... medium dark).

You can apparently also change the dirty_circle or dirty_indicator png files directly, but I couldn't find good replacements on the web and when I tried to modify some directly in paint the results were weird - I would get a nice bright grey box housing the circle with the color I wanted instead of just the circle.

**The change:**

simply add into the above block `"layer3.tint":[255,161,52]` or whatever RBG color you want.  Also, change the opacity from 0.5 to 1.0 or it will be very muted.  One unintended consequence is that when you hover over the dirty file dot the 'x' will now be colored a translucent version of whatever color you set the dirty dot to, as opposed to the default light colored x.  I'm sure there is a way to fix this that has to do with the dirty_x attributes but I'm tired of messing with it.

Also, not sure if this is relevant but some others on SO and various forums mentioned that making the change directly in the `Default.sublime-theme`  file can have unintended consequences, and they advocated making a copy of this file within the `packages/user` folder and making the changes there, since apparently this file is loaded independently and applied after and on top of the default changes.